# dataWithContentsOfURL versus downloadTaskWithURL

Tags: ios, ios7

when I am fetching image data using the url retrieved from another web service, and I need to update the model object, I always have problems updating the corresponding views. Essentially, here is the issue:

1. Calls Web Service A
2. Retrieve Image URL - First Call returns block
3. Calls Web Service using Image URL
4. Retrieve Image Data
5. Update Model Object with image data
6. Update View Object thumbnail (eg:uicollectionviewcell or uitableviewcell) based on model object (Problem occurs here)

I've used this approach before in AFNetworking and correspondingly, NSURLSession. However, the problem is, after I have updated the model object, I need to scroll the collection view or table view before the thumbnail images appear. Otherwise, on first load, the images remain blank.

Please see the code below for an example of this approach:

```
- (void)searchFlickrForTerm:(NSString *) term completionBlock:(FlickrSearchCompletionBlock) completionBlock
{
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration  defaultSessionConfiguration];
_session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config
                                         delegate:self
                                    delegateQueue:nil];

NSString *requestString = [Flickr flickrSearchURLForSearchTerm:term];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    if (error != nil) {
        completionBlock(term,nil,error);
    }
    else{
        NSDictionary *searchResultsDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        //This is the segment where we parse the Flickr data
        NSString * status = searchResultsDict[@"stat"];
        if ([status isEqualToString:@"fail"]) {
            NSError * error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"FlickrSearch" code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: searchResultsDict[@"message"]}];
            completionBlock(term, nil, error);
        } else {

            NSArray *objPhotos = searchResultsDict[@"photos"][@"photo"];
            NSMutableArray *flickrPhotos = [@[] mutableCopy];
            for(NSMutableDictionary *objPhoto in objPhotos)
            {
                //Good Idea to parse in the web service call itself. The structure might be different
                //If parse in the model class, can be very complicated if the structure is different
                FlickrPhoto *photo = [[FlickrPhoto alloc] init];
                photo.farm = [objPhoto[@"farm"] intValue];
                photo.server = [objPhoto[@"server"] intValue];
                photo.secret = objPhoto[@"secret"];
                photo.photoID = [objPhoto[@"id"] longLongValue];

                NSString *searchURL = [Flickr flickrPhotoURLForFlickrPhoto:photo size:@"m"];
                //Call to retrieve image data
                NSURLSessionDownloadTask *getImageTask = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchURL] completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                    UIImage *downloadImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];
                    photo.thumbnail = downloadImage;
                }];

                [getImageTask resume];
                [flickrPhotos addObject:photo];
            }

            completionBlock(term,flickrPhotos,nil);
        }
        //End parse of Flickr Data
    }
}];

[dataTask resume];
//End
}
```

In the above code segment, after I have parse the FlickrPhoto model object, I use NSURLDownloadTask to call the url of the image. This is the code segment in question.

Approach A:

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *getImageTask = [_session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchURL] completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    UIImage *downloadImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];
     photo.thumbnail = downloadImage;
}];

[getImageTask resume];
```

However, as mentioned earlier, even after I have updated the photo.thumbnail property, in my uicollectionview where I set my imageView to read from the thumbnail property, the images do not show up on my collection view unless I scroll.

However, the interesting thing is that, instead of using NSURLDownloadTask, and I instead just use dataWithContentsOfURL, the images show up without me needing to scroll the collection view.

Approach B:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchURL]
                                                          options:0
                                                            error:&error];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
photo.thumbnail = image;
```

I have no idea why this is the case. I have also reload the collection view data by grabbing the main thread in my view controller.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.collectionView reloadData];
        });
```

I really apologize for this lengthy post, but I would really appreciate if anyone could advice me on this. I have read through the documentation, but I have yet been able to find a meaningful answer to this puzzling issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I know the issue, after studying Apple's documentation closely.

Essentially, in my approach A, downloadTaskWithURL will spin off another background thread. Hence, even though I have updated the model object, the view will not be updated with the new information unless I grab the main thread again and refresh the view.

However, in approach B, dataWithContentsOfURL runs synchronously. Hence, there is no issue of the background thread at all.

From apple documentation:

> **dataWithContentsOfURL:**
>   Returns a data object containing the data from the location specified by a given URL.
>
> **Discussion**
>   This method is ideal for converting data:// URLs to NSData objects, and can also be used for reading short files **synchronously**. If you need to read potentially large files, use inputStreamWithURL: to open a stream, then read the file a piece at a time.

Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong in my understanding. I am happy to change my accepted answer to yours if I think the solution answers my doubts better.